# How CI connect oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

**I want to know step by step CI connect oracle**
I tried But an error like this -->>>>

> Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_3_0_1\system\database\drivers\oci8\oci8_driver.php

Answer (score 0):

You must configure correctly your XAMPP installation, you can do this adding the correct dll name to php.ini file. If you don't have the dll that's provide the function `oci_connect()` you could download the unique version of XAMPP that come with that dll precompiled for windows, at least i think, here's the link https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/

if you chose download this version of XAMPP make sure that you edit the php.ini file and edit the line where say something like `php_oci8.dll` and that's all. Restart the Apache Service in XAMPP Control Panel and you could beginning to development.

You must know that this version of XAMPP has an older version of PHP. You decide